# Guidance making interactive buttons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and I am stuck on exactly how to start in my text editor? I've tried googling but I'm getting mixed answers.

I'm trying to make four interactive buttons in a browser.  I just don't know how to start?  My file is open and the text editor is aware I am using JavaScript.

Now, do I need to start with a script tag?  Then what should be the next steps?  If anyone could provide me with a little guidance on how I should be thinking in my steps id greatly appreciate it.. Thank you very much

Comment: Please read [ask], [Posting an Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2813224), and how to post your code as a [mcve] before posting a question. When you're ready to post your code
⏩[look for the brackets `<>` button](https://i.ibb.co/935zWhk/mcve.jpg)⏪

Answer (score 1):

Start with the **Hello World** of using a Button HTML tag and script that handles a click event.

For example -- here is the Button defined in HTML.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" id="HelloButton">Say  Hello</button>
```

Now in a separate JS Script, you can handle the click event:

```
$(function() {

    $("#HelloButton" ).click(function($e) {

       alert("Say Hello"); 
        
    } );// END of the button click event
 } );
```

This uses JQUERY as well (in case you want to follow it).

Comment: The question isn't tagged with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple starting page - *without* using any libraries (like jQuery) or frameworks (like react or vue)

```js
// define the button actions here:

document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(btn=>btn.onclick=ev=>console.log(`Hey, you have clicked the ${btn.textContent} button!}`));
```

```html
<button>one</button>
<button>two</button>
<button>three</button>
<button>four</button><br>
<textarea>edit your text here ...
</textarea>
```

In order for the script to work it needs to run *after* the page has loaded. In Stackoverflow snippets (see above) that is always the case. However, in your page you need to either put the `<script>` tag after your `<body>` element or put it into the callback function of the `window.onload()` event.